# Add nofollow to link

Tags: php, wordpress

So i try to write function, that add nofollow to links in wordpress with different domains.

The problem is in **else** because it don't work...

```
if(strpos($link, $domain) !== FALSE){
    return $link.'good';
}
else{
    return $link.'bad'; 
}
```

Filter returns links only with **good**, if link is **bad**, filter return only link...

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
$domain = 'somedomain.com';

if(strpos($link, $domain) !== FALSE){
    return $link.'good';
}
else{
    return $link.'bad'; 
}
```

It return, when checking different links:

```
<a href="http://lol.com"  target="_blank">LOL1</a>
<br/>
<a href="http://somedomain.com" target="_blank">LOL2</a>
good
```

So as you can see, it should return **lol** with **bad**

Comment: Please could you provide an example of $link and $domain?

Comment: @psych just aded full example

Comment: Thanks, so what is the value of $link? Is it just the href value? If strpos isn't returning false, it will return the position of the matched string. This should help you identify what the problem is. Sorry, I can't see anything wrong with your code at the moment.

Comment: @psych i also cant see anything wrong, but it don't work...

Comment: @psych just understood that wordpress in the $link gives all links in the post but i thought it was one by one as the loop...

Comment: Did my answer below answer your question?

Comment: @psych no, the problem was in other thing

Comment: Is that not what I said in my answer below? Sorry if this did not help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the value of $link isn't what you are expecting. If the value of

```
if(strpos($link, $domain) !== FALSE)
```

is not equal to false, it will return the position of the matched string.

Inspect $link and the value of this function to see what has been matched. You might be passing in multiple anchor tags by mistake?

Comment: as i said, $link is a string of all links in post, but in firs i thought i was only one by one link in loop.

Comment: I believe this is what I said in my answer? The code is correct, but $link is not what you thought? 

Please mark as correct answer if you agree.